# Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$, $u = a + x $ is a unit and $x \in J(R)$, prove $a$ is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> **Definition**: For a ring with unit $R$, Jacobson Radical is defined as the ideal $J(R) = \{r \in R: rM = 0 \}$ where $M$ is simple.
>
> 1. Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$, $u = a + x $ is a unit and $x \in J(R)$, prove $a$ is a unit.

1. So I wrote that if $M$ is simple, let $m \in M$. Then $um = (a + x)m = am + xm = am$. So therefore $um = am \iff (u-a)m = 0 \iff u - a \in J(R).$ But this is where I am stuck. To show $a$ is a unit, I have to show $a \not\in J(R)$ at least. Now I think here I have to assume $J(R) \neq R$, then this gives me $u \not\in J(R)$ since $J(R)$ is an ideal of $R$, so therefore $a \not\in J(R)$. But I am still stuck. I tried also using $u$ being a unit to generate $1$, but I can't get any leads.

**EDIT**: I just realized $J(R)$ can be defined as the intersection of right maximal ideals in $R$ and I can turn the problem into showing $x\not\in J(R) $, but I was only able to show $1-sx$ is non-unit. where $s\in R.$

Comment: I deleted the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDIT**: **I just realized $J(R)$ can be defined as the intersection of right maximal ideals in $R$** and I can turn the problem into showing $x\not\in J(R) $, but I was only able to show $1-sx$ is non-unit. where $s\in R.$

If you believe the bolded characterization above, AND that its left-hand analogue is the same set, then there is a fast solution (not along the lines you were pursuing.)

Suppose $u=a+x$ as in your hypotheses, and that $a$ is not a unit. Then $a$ is contained in some maximal left ideal or some maximal right ideal, call it $A$.  In that case, $x\in A$ also, by the characterizations mentioned above.

But since $A$ is additively closed, that would mean $u\in A$ as well, but when an ideal contains a unit, it is the entire ring.  This would contradict the fact that $A$ is proper.

Therefore $a$ must be a unit.

Comment: When I wrote the bolded statement, I was thinking about a commutative case. When I tried to justify it for the general case, it falls short. Let $X$ be a simple left module, since $J(R) = \cap \operatorname{ann}{X}$

then $\operatorname{ann}(X) = \{r \in R: rX = 0\} = \{r : rR/m=0\} = \{r :r(s + m) = m, s\in R \} = \{r: rs \in m \}$

But if we aren't in a commutative ring, how do we know $r \in m$?

Comment: @Hawk what exactly are you trying to justify now? Symmetry of the radical?

Comment: The two equivalent definitions of the radical.

Comment: That is, for a $R$ with $1$ and $M$ is a simple right module, $J(R) = \{x: Mx = 0 \}
 = \cap m$ where m is some maximal right ideal in $R.$

Comment: @Hawk Usially one resorts to other characterizations to show the symmetry. For example [it is explained here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/qchu.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/the-jacobson-radical/amp/)

Comment: Why does he have $m =1$? I thought $M$ is a module, what is the $1$ element in a module?

Comment: I actually have a very similar active question relating to this, but I think I figured he meant $r = 1$

Comment: @Hawk you’re not seeing that in the case he’s talking about, $M=R/I$ and he really should have written the coset $1+I=m$

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is not a unit then $aR$ is a proper right ideal of $R$, so there is a maximal right ideal $m$ with $aR \subset m$. But then $a \in m$, and $x \in J(R) \subset m$ since $J(R)$ is the intersection of all the maximal right ideals, so $u \in m$, but $u$ is a unit, which contradicts $m$ being a maximal ideal.

Comment: "If $a$ is not a unit then $aR$ is a proper right ideal of $R$". This is not necessarily true unless you assume commutativity. There are rings in which there are elements $a,b$ such that $ab=1$ and $ba\neq 1$, and in such rings $a$ is a nonunit and is not contained in any proper right ideal but it is contained in a proper left ideal.